# Observe callback is not being triggered with Kotlin coroutines Flow and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I'm new to Android development and trying to understand Coroutines and `LiveData` from various example projects. I have currently setup a function to call my api when the user has input a username and password. However after 1 button press, the app seems to jam and I can't make another api call as if its stuck on a pending process.

This is my first android app made with a mash of ideas so please let me know where I've made mistakes!

Activity:

```
binding.bLogin.setOnClickListener {
        val username = binding.etUsername.text.toString()
        val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString()
        viewModel.userClicked(username, password).observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let { resource ->
                when (resource.status) {
                    Status.SUCCESS -> {
                        print(resource.data)
                    }
                    Status.ERROR -> {
                        print(resource.message)
                    }
                    Status.LOADING -> {
                        // loader stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        })
 }
```

ViewModel:

```
fun userClicked(username: String, password: String) = liveData(dispatcherIO) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
        try {
            userRepository.login(username, password).apply {
                emit(Resource.success(null))
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.error(exception.message ?: "Error Occurred!", data = null))
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun login(
    username: String,
    password: String
): Flow<Resource<String?>> {
    return flow {
        emit(Resource.loading(null))
        api.login(LoginRequest(username, password)).apply {
            this.onSuccessSuspend {
                data?.let {
                    prefs.apiToken = it.key
                    emit(Resource.success(null))
                }
            }
        }.onErrorSuspend {
            emit(Resource.error(message(), null))
        }.onExceptionSuspend {
            emit(Resource.error(message(), null))
        }
    }.flowOn(dispatcherIO)
}
```

API:

```
suspend fun login(@Body request: LoginRequest): ApiResponse<Auth>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to launch a coroutine in `liveData` builder, it is already `suspend` so you can call `suspend` functions there:

```
fun userClicked(username: String, password: String) = liveData(dispatcherIO) {
    emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
    try {
        userRepository.login(username, password).apply {
            emit(Resource.success(null))
        }
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        emit(Resource.error(exception.message ?: "Error Occurred!", data = null))
    }
}
```

If you want to use `LiveDate` with `Flow` you can convert `Flow` to `LiveData` object using [`asLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).asLiveData(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext,kotlin.Long)) function:

```
fun userClicked(username: String, password: String): LiveData<Resource<String?>> {
    return userRepository.login(username, password).asLiveData()
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend to mix up `LiveData` and `Flow` streams in the project. I suggest to use only `Flow`.

Using only `Flow`:

```
// In ViewModel:

fun userClicked(username: String, password: String): Flow<Resource<String?>> {
    return userRepository.login(username, password)
}

// Activity

binding.bLogin.setOnClickListener {
        val username = binding.etUsername.text.toString()
        val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString()
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.userClicked(username, password).collect { resource ->
                when (resource.status) {
                    Status.SUCCESS -> {
                        print(resource.data)
                    }
                    Status.ERROR -> {
                        print(resource.message)
                    }
                    Status.LOADING -> {
                        // loader stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Remove `suspend` keyword from the `login` function in `Repository`.

[`lifecycleScope` docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope).

Comment: thanks, ive dropped this code in to simplify, it still doesnt seem to have solved the issue that the app isnt making the call / reacting properly for some reason though

Comment: @jwarris91 please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, what goes in `Flow<...>` and what do i need to change in the repository layer?

Comment: In `Flow<...>` you use `Resource` data, nothing to change in repository.

Comment: ah ok, im being told that the VM func needs to be suspend marked? and im getting an error on `Flow<Resource<String?>>`  "No type arguments expected for class Flow"

Comment: also an error in the activity for the resource result of the userClicked "Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly."

Comment: Make sure you use `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow` not `java.util.concurrent.Flow`

Comment: thanks, that cleared up the fun signature error, but it still wants it marked as suspend in the VM? and still have the type confusion in the Activity

Comment: It seems in the Repository you can remove `suspend` from the `login` function. I guess the error should disappear after removing `suspend` keyword.

Comment: thansk all seems to work now! so the issue was mixing 2 libraries i didnt need to? coroutines and livedata vs flow?

Comment: Right, you can mix them, but don't need to, better to use one stream.